# Discoverability of edit-tags

Tags: feature-request

As well as hovering over a question's tags revealing the 'edit-tags' option, hover over edit (for the question) to do so too.  That's the more important one to reveal it for.

**Reasoning:** people are still doing whole edits to edit tags alone.

If you agree with the above, also consider changing the position of the revealed edit-tags link - so that edit-tags, when it appears, is directly under edit.

**Reasoning:** it is a sub function of edit.  Putting it 'on its own' as currently is a bit weird.